# Wordpress database data fetching

Tags: php, database, wordpress

| Name | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | a@mail |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | @ |
| 13 | Samudra News Alerts |
| 0 | B |
| 1 | B@mail |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | # |
| 13 | South Asia News Alerts |
| 0 | C |
| 1 | c@mail |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | $ |
| 13 | Samudra News Alerts South Asia News Alerts |

PHP

```
<?php  
    global $wpdb;
    $states = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE name=13");
    $state1="";
    foreach ( $states as $state ) {
        $state1 = $state->value;
    }
    
        if($state1 == "Samudra News Alerts" || $state1 == "Samudra News Alerts South Asia News Alerts" || $state1 == "Samudra News Alerts ICSF Publications and Films Alerts"){ 
             $mails = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE name=1"); 
            foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {     
                echo "<center><td>'".$mail->value."',</td></center>";
            }
        } else{}
   
?>
```

Above this is my database and PHP, I need to filter email details when it is available in Samudra News Alerts. how do i filter it

Comment: "I need to filter email details when it is available in Samudra News Alerts. how do i filter it" 

What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: i need to collect email id which is in Samudra News Alerts

Comment: The table above doesn't make clear to me how your database table structure is built.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/25en6i5 look here our database details

Comment: i wand output like  Samudra News Alerts Emails (a@mail,c@mail)

Comment: SELECT (email) FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE value LIKE 'Samudra%'

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
            $states = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE name=1 AND lead_id IN(SELECT lead_id FROM wp_vxcf_leads_detail WHERE name=13 AND value LIKE 'Samudra%' ) ");    
            foreach ( $states as $state ) 

            {       
               echo "'".$state->value."',";
            }
```

This Code is working for me